# jquery.fn getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my site I have a jquery function created by using the jQuery.fn method like so:

```
jQuery.fn.equalHeights = function() {
    var currentTallest = 0;
    jQuery(this).each(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).height() > currentTallest) {
            currentTallest = jQuery(this).height();
        }
    });
    jQuery(this).css('min-height', currentTallest);
};
```

I use this function to equalize the size of sidebars on my site so I call it after the page has finished loading to make sure everything is in place before I do the sizing.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('#sidebar-one, #sidebar-two, #content').equalHeights();
});
```

This works perfectly except for on some of my pages users will add another instance of the jQuery library to their page in the body area (for whatever reason).  This second library causes my function to stop working properly. I'm assuming this is because the second jQuery overwrites any functions created with the jQuery.fn method.  Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Notes:  My site is running Drupal 7 so I can't easily move the scripts to the bottom of the page.  The equalHeights function was not written by me; I believe I found it here on stack so my knowledge of the fn method (and JS in general) is not that extensive.

---

---

**EDIT**: Based on all the great suggestions below, this is how I finally got it to work.

First, I give my "default" instance of jQuery a new variable to reference:

```
var JQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Second, I call the more efficient version of the equalHeights function using the new jQuery variable:

```
JQ.fn.equalHeights = function() {
    var tallest = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        var h = JQ(this).height();
        tallest = h > tallest ? h : tallest;
    }).css("minHeight", tallest);
};
```

Third, I call my function using the new jQuery variable:

```
JQ('#sidebar-one, #sidebar-two, #content').equalHeights();
```

So now any time I need to reference my original jQuery library I just use JQ and I don't have to worry about another library stepping on any of my functions.

I realize this isn't the best way to fix this problem and I'm going to work on eliminating the additional jQuery libraries but this will at least keep my sidebars properly sized in the mean time.

Comment: NB: there's no need to wrap `this` inside a plugin, although you will need to inside the `.each` loop - just do `return this.each(...).css(...)`

Comment: I've been trying to pull it out of the plugin without success.  I'll try your `return this.each()` and see how that works.

Comment: I was only talking about inside a plugin.  Anyhow, you probably need `$.noconflict()` to give yourself a persistent reference to the master copy of jQuery that will not be overwritten by a later copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your snippet in a module IEFE, passing the "old" jQuery reference:

```
(function($) {
    // $ will always point to the jQuery version with the `equalHeights` method
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#sidebar-one, #sidebar-two, #content').equalHeights();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

See also [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noconflict/) for further tricks.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work.  Drupal's jQuery already has noConflict turned on and the tricks mentioned on the page don't seem to do the trick either...

Comment: I figured out the problem and it's now working as expected.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could technically copy jQuery to a new variable just for your use - i.e. `JQ = jQuery;` then do `JQ(this)...`

Though you may just want to address the insertion of subsequent versions - stopping it, or ensuring your version is added last and all of your code is executed afterwards so they can't override it

Comment: I wish I could prevent the addition of subsequent versions.  The problem is, this is being added by one of our programmers and I don't have the pay grade to stop him.  I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: @Cloudkiller Just tell him, he won't eat you.

Comment: Yea, it'd be much more efficient to describe the problem to them - if you're both working on the same site, you shouldn't be fighting each other's code

Comment: I'm still fighting the div > table fight and I'll wait until I win that battle first.

Comment: Sounds like the guy's a <naughty word here> - any other developers to back up your side?

Comment: We're basically a team of two trying to manage a massive university site. I'm sure he'd take out the library if I asked nicely enough but sometimes it's easier to fix the issue on my end, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Cloudkiller Using two versions of jQuery will only create way more problems than it solves. You should try and convince your brogrammer to stick with jQuery 1.4.4 if that is the only version that works without compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the second version of jQuery will overwrite the previous one. Unless you are using a legacy library that isn't compatible with later versions of jQuery, there's no reason to load two different versions.

To use a later version of jQuery with Drupal 7 you need to use the [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) script and then add something like the following to your Drupal theme (courtesy of [oldwildissue](http://oldwildissue.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/drupal-7-manually-update-jquery-version/)):

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  //We define the path of our new jquery core file
  //assuming we are using the minified version 1.8.3
  $jquery_path = drupal_get_path('theme','MYTHEME') . '/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js';

  //We duplicate the important information from the Drupal one
  $javascript[$jquery_path] = $javascript['misc/jquery.js'];
  //..and we update the information that we care about
  $javascript[$jquery_path]['version'] = '1.8.3';
  $javascript[$jquery_path]['data'] = $jquery_path;

  //Then we remove the Drupal core version
  unset($javascript['misc/jquery.js']);
}
```

This will allow you to use any version of jQuery with Drupal 7.

I also noticed that your plugin is using some pretty bad practices. Here's an optimized version of your plugin, using good and well established practices:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.equalHeights = function() {
        var tallest = 0;
        return this.each(function(){
            var h = $(this).height();
            tallest = h > tallest ? h : tallest;
        }).css("minHeight", tallest);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimized plugin, I really appreciate it.  Drupal 7 by default uses jQuery 1.4 and the programmer who is adding in additional libraries is using 1.8.  There's a module to update Drupal's core jQuery but it introduces some other issues that I haven't dealt with yet.  It's all complicated, but what isn't.

Comment: @Cloudkiller I see! I added info on how to use any version of jQuery with Drupal 7. If you have compatibility issues, that's a whole different story and a pain to solve :(

Comment: Thanks for the code but I'm not brave enough to turn on 1.8 on my site yet.  We have 20k+ pages and checking them to see what 1.8 broke/changed is something I'll save for the Drupal 8 launch.